# Error when trying to set the $JAVA_HOME - Error : JAVA_HOME is not set

Tags: bash, centos, java-home

I have Linux CentOS release 5.5 and i'm trying to install sun-java6-jdk.

I've noticed that if i execute the following command, i have:

```
 java -version
 java version "1.6.0_21"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b06)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

If i do:

```
 echo $JAVA_HOME
 /usr/java/default
```

When i try to run a script, i have the error:
Error : JAVA_HOME is not set.

How can i find and set the right value in the $JAVA_HOME in .bashrc file?

Thanks, in advance

Comment: How and from where are you running this script?

Comment: are you sure this variable has been exported by the shell? If its not then it'll show up when you try to `echo` it, but programs still wont see it. To verify run `env|grep JAVA_HOME`

Comment: I run the script as super user(sudo), i executed the following command,  env|grep JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your JAVA_HOME variable is exported to the environment of subsequently executed commands.

In your .bashrc file put:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
```

Comment: Finally, i added the line --export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default-- in the conf/hadoop-env.sh file and it worked. It's working now

Answer (score 1):

To find $JAVA_HOME value, do

```
ls -l `which java`
```

and use the parent directory of /bin/java
Which script displays the "JAVA_HOME is not set"? If its a startup script of tomcat or so, you better set the $JAVA_HOME in that script.

Comment: You can use `type -p java` which is a bash builtin: `JAVA_HOME=$(dirname "$(dirname "$(type -p java)")")`

Comment: It'a a script .sh for Hadoop, i need to start the namenode but i can't

Comment: Also, i executed the command ls -l `which java` and the output is: /usr/bin/java -> /usr/java/jre1.6.0_21/bin/java

Comment: ALso, you can run "type java" .